# Azure VM Performance issues

Tags: azure

I am a user of the Bizspark program and I am testing the Azure cloud features on a DS2_V2 virtual machine (2 cores, 7GB of RAM) with Windows Server 2016 Datacenter in the Western US and I am worried about machine performance.

In tests I used a standard Apache Server, PHP7 and MySQL Server installations. In Apache I hosted a simple eCommerce Web page without using any DNS to redirect, that is, I was accessing the page directly through the DNS address provided by the Azure portal.

In a basic Amazon Webservices machine (1 core, 1GB of RAM) also in the Western US followed the same installation procedures as those of Azure.

Result: The Azure server always takes at least twice as long to respond to any request, be it a page opening, a remote database query or even a PHP script querying the local database .

As an example: opening the page on Azure took 9 seconds until it started loading on the screen. On Amazon, loading started in 4 seconds.

My question, which was not answered by a Microsoft technician in a recent support call, is: what can impact a machine's performance in this way?

Comment: From what I have been able to analyze most of the problems is about latency and response time, not the machine's own processing.

The Amazon machine mentioned answers me pings with a mean of 150ms while Azure's has at least 500ms of latency, even if testing within my geographic region (south of Brazil) ... even if I test the speed using certain websites The datacenters in the USA respond faster than the locals, which has no logic whatsoever.

Comment: You can use tracert to test Azure and Amazon IPs, find the difference between them. Then test the DNS resolution latency.

Comment: All my recent tests result in same result: Azure's latency is too high to my region. Any other provider, including some out of America, have a lower latency. Nothing let me to believe that is a internet provider problem because I have no problems with Amazon, including servers hosted on UK. The Azure support team can't even tell me why South America servers have a latency higher to me than those on US (I'm on Brazil, btw).

Comment: Which azure region shows the lowest latency for you? http://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net Certainly consider moving the VM closer to you.

Comment: AzureSpeedTest ever shows me Brazilian South (closest one) with at least 500ms. West USA, sometimes, shows 300ms but never less than this. Amazon's West USA ping is 80ms average.